# all possible combination of multiple arrays corresponding to multiple arguments in an integral function 

Tags: r, for-loop, data.table, apply

I've modified the question a little bit.

```
     integg <- function(t,a,b,con,s){   
  u <- ifelse(t - a < 0 ,0, t - a) 
  l <- ifelse(t - (a+b) < 0,0, t - (a+b))  
  s * integrate(Vectorize(function(foo,x){x}),lower=l,upper=u,x=con)      
}
```

This equation will give me an integral value, and I have 3 arrays:  As, Bs, and Ss which represent arguments 'a','b', and 's'.

Let's say the arrays are as follows:

```
As <- seq(from=50,to=60,by=0.01)
Bs <- seq(from=130,to=140,by=0.01)
Ss <- seq(from=0.0001,to=0.01,by=0.0001)
# con is a constant
con <- 55
# I have 7 values for t and I want to do one at a time, 
# so for this example I have t=360
t <- 360
# although I'll want to do also for my other values c(0,20,40,60,120,240)
```

My final goal is to test every combination of these arrays As, Bs, and Ss w/ each other. I've been trying to use outer and have been unsuccessful w/ looping afterwards.

```
# first make one array w/ all possible combinations
all_poss <- outer(As,Bs,paste)
# now include the third array
all_poss <- outer(all_poss,Ss,paste)

head(all_poss)
> [1] "50 130 1e-04"    "50.01 130 1e-04" "50.02 130 1e-04" 
  [4] "50.03 130 1e-04" "50.04 130 1e-04" "50.05 130 1e-04"


    ### I would have to change my integg function a little bit, to deal w/ the pasted items
      integg2 <- function(t,con,all){  
    a <- strsplit(h,split=' ')[[1]][1]
    b <- strsplit(h,split=' ')[[1]][2]
    s <- strsplit(h,split=' ')[[1]][3]   

    u <- ifelse(t - a < 0 ,0, t - a) 
    l <- ifelse(t - (a+b) < 0,0, t - (a+b))  
    s * integrate(Vectorize(function(foo,x){x}),lower=l,upper=u,x=con)   
}

     ### I would then need to loop integg2() somehow through my list of all possibilities

      all_vals <- sapply(all_poss,integg2)
      # I haven't gotten this to work, but i'm not sure this is 
      # even an efficient way to do what I want
```

I need some kind of loop here at the end, if anyone has any better ideas of how to combine all possibilities of these arrays and a more efficient way of looping let me know.

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `expand.grid` will create a data frame with all combinations of the vector/factor you feed into it. Another way is to use joins with `data.table.

`integrate` returns a list; you probably want the value by using `$value`.

I also changed the variable names for personal preference (and I dislike having name overlaps with built-in functions like `t`).

```
av <- seq(from=50,to=60,by=0.01)
bv <- seq(from=130,to=140,by=0.01)
sv <- seq(from=0.0001,to=0.01,by=0.0001)
tv <- c(seq(from=0,to=60,by=20),seq(from=120,to=360,by=120))
con <- 55

##method 1: using built-in functions (warning: can be slower and memory-intensive)
cmb <- expand.grid(list(av=av,bv=bv,sv=sv,tv=tv))
cmb <- within(cmb,{
    u <- ifelse(tv - av < 0 ,0, tv - av)
    l <- ifelse(tv - (av+bv) < 0,0, tv - (av+bv))
    value <- sv * mapply(function(...){integrate(...)$value},
        lower=l,upper=u,
        MoreArgs=list(f=Vectorize(function(x,constant){constant}),constant=con))
})

##method 2: using package data.table (for speed and efficient memory use)
dt.av <- data.table(av,k=1,key="k")
dt.bv <- data.table(bv,k=1,key="k")
dt.sv <- data.table(sv,k=1,key="k")
dt.tv <- data.table(tv,k=1,key="k")
cmb <- dt.av[dt.bv[dt.sv[dt.tv]]] #joins together
cmb[,u := ifelse(tv - av < 0 ,0, tv - av)]
cmb[,l := ifelse(tv - (av+bv) < 0,0, tv - (av+bv))]
cmb[,value:=mapply(function(...){integrate(...)$value},
    lower=l,upper=u,
    MoreArgs=list(f=Vectorize(function(x,constant){constant}),constant=con)
)]
```

Comment: maybe i'm missing this, but there is no argument for 'con' in integg2()

Comment: If the function `integg2` cannot find the variable `con` in its immediate environment, it will look to the main environment for a function value. So defining `con` outside the function should work. Alternatively, add `con` as an argument of the function.

Comment: @LucasPinto I have changed the function to include the constant as an argument. I have also fixed the `expand.grid` call so that the data frame columns are named correctly.

Comment: Ya, i did that too. not a big deal

Comment: I'm not quite sure how you got this to run, if I don't run tv as single numbers, the data frame is too large

Comment: I tested the code on a small subset, not the entire thing (my machine complained, too). I wanted to make this as general as possible. Running a single `tv` at a time should be fine as well.

Comment: this doesn't pertain to the intial question...but...if I take out 'sv' from integg2() the function won't cycle through all combinations of the other two arguments (av and bv), it looks like it just prints the first combo for the entire df of $value

Comment: I am debugging. What exactly is the function that you want to integrate over? As it stands, it looks like you are integrating over a constant function.

Comment: that's right whatever constant I input for 'con' in this case that's 55

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16260/discussion-between-blue-magister-and-lucas-pinto)